# Multi GPU seems not work on TensorFlow1.0

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow 1.0 and I have develop a simple program to measure performance. I have a silly model as follow

```
def model(example_batch):
    h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=example_batch, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    h2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h1, units=2)
    return h2
```

and a simple function to run the simulation:

```
def testPerformanceFromMemory(model, iter=1000 num_cores=2):
  example_batch = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=(64, 128))
  for core in range(num_cores):
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%core):
      prediction = model(example_batch)
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
  sess.run(init_op)
  tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
  input_array = np.random.random((64,128))
  for step in range(iter):
    myprediction = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={example_batch:input_array})
```

if I run the python script and then run nvidia-smi command I can see that GPU0 is running with a high percentage of usage but GPU1 is 0 % usage.

I read this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu and this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py but I don't know why my example doesn't run in multi gpu.

PS If I doenload ciphar 10 example from tensorflow repository it run in a multigpu mode.

Edit: As mrry says I am overwriting prediction so, I post here the correct way:

```
def testPerformanceFromMemory(model, iter=1000 num_cores=2):
  example_batch = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=(64, 128))
  prediction = []
  for core in range(num_cores):
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%core):
      prediction.append([model(example_batch)])
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
  sess.run(init_op)
  tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
  input_array = np.random.random((64,128))
  for step in range(iter):
    myprediction = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={example_batch:input_array})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your program, you are creating several parallel subgraphs (often called "towers") on different GPU devices, but overwriting the `prediction` tensor in each iteration of the first `for` loop:

```
for core in range(num_cores):
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%core):
    prediction = model(example_batch)
# ...
for step in range(iter):
  myprediction = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={example_batch:input_array})
```

As a result, when you call `sess.run(prediction, ...)` you will only be running the subgraph that was created in the final iteration of the first `for` loop, which only runs on one GPU.